# Create mosaic like Voronoi Diagram from disjoint polygons

Tags: polygon-creation, voronoi-thiessen

The illustration below shows [the problem](https://github.com/lucasmation/corrige_setor_censitario_2010):

[image]

as in *(a)* I have **a set of disjoint polygons, as geometries** in PostGIS. I need something like *(b)*, the  ["mosaic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation#Voronoi_tilings) of this set of polygons, building it by a "influence region" criteria... Is like a Voronoi construction (illustrated by *(c)*): in fact, if the polygons was points, the influence regions are Voronoi.

Summarizing: I need a **SQL algorithm (or some specific for PostGIS)  that generates the "mosaic" of a set of disjoint polygons.** 
(perhaps a loop of little ST_Buffer and ST_Difference operations)

PS: I need, like Voronoi's, that space delimitation (a squared frame in *(b)*) is ignored.

---

This problem is similar to [this other about lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104631/create-voronoi-diagram-from-line-segments).

EDIT (after @FelixIP comment)

I preffer to stay in *vector* universe, to not lost precision (ex. using [ST_DelaunayTriangles](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DelaunayTriangles.html) and adding and subtracting interiors by the original polygons, them adapting a [dual graph solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115729/7505))... Some simple and automatic packages like [pprepair](https://github.com/tudelft3d/pprepair) (assisted like [QGIS topological tools](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/topology.html#figure-topological-tools) are not automatic).
But *raster* is perhaps simpler and less CPU-consuming.

This "GRID process" illustration  is also valid as solution, assuming that it can allowing same precision and "euclidean influence region growing".

[image]

In ARCGIS exists a spatial analysis tool known as [Euclidean Allocation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/euclidean-allocation.htm), so, perhaps there are a [PostGIS similar solution](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/PostGIS_Raster_SoC_Idea_2012/Distance_Analysis_Tools), starting with the set of polygons (classifying, rasterizing and making-back the polygons).

Comment: Thanks @Nir, sorry the confusion with points, I am not using points, only polygons as items *(a)* and *(b)* of the illustration... Do you have a link of your clue about solution?

Comment: In arcgis there is a raster solution called eucledean allocation or proximity

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP, I edited to "well come raster solutions" ;-)

Comment: If you erase your polygons from their extent.aspolygon, you'll be left with polygon. Skeleton of it http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177/simplifying-polygons-to-linestring is what you need I guess. Implementation is a biggie  though

Comment: Not answers to you problem but probably interesting http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104631/create-voronoi-diagram-from-line-segments and http://www.voronoi.com/wiki/images/7/76/Voronoi_diagrams_of_line_segments_made_easy.pdf.

Comment: Is your question still relevant for you or has it already lost its relevance after so much time?

Comment: Hi @Cyril, I am not working full time with PostGIS at this moment, but you well-come to post updated answer (it is pending to accept so I can accept yours)... PostGIS (there are [ST_VoronoiPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_VoronoiPolygons.html)!) and PostGIS Raster has evolved a lot,

Comment: Well, I will try ... but only I will not be responsible for the quality of the scripts, the method is important to me ...

Comment: @Cyril, I can review your scripts... Next week. Posting something that seems a solution with modern PostGIS functions,  will be a good first step.

Comment: See also [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/238936/7505), near duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I will prepare a cake for you - fruit platter, using PostGIS tools, as you requested, if I correctly understood the question, and as I mentioned, the responsibility for the operation of the PostGIS oven is borne by her creative team.

I will ask not to be offended by anyone in my humorous style and to understand it as a game!

The original file is sliced fruit and simple shapes (hereinafter referred to as fruit), see Figure 1 below.

[image]

Here is my recipe, and I will be helped in this by dear programmers, whom you will learn about later.
Let's begin, and for this we will create a dough in which our fruits will be laid, for which run the script:

`create table poly_extent as SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(ST_Envelope(ST_Extent(geom)),0.05),4326) as geom FROM poly;`

See the result in Figure 2 below

[image]

Now, if there are few fruits, like in my picture, create the border of the external buffer on the fruit, or if there are many fruits, create the border of the negative buffer, for which run the script:

`create table poly_buff_dump as  SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(ST_Union(ST_Buffer((geom),0.01, 'join=mitre mitre_limit=5.0'))))).geom) geom FROM poly;`

And slice the buffer lines around each fruit

`UPDATE poly_buff_dump SET geom=ST_RemovePoint(geom, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)  WHERE ST_IsClosed(geom)=true;`

See the result in Figure 3 below

[image]

(Actually, I thought that as a result I would get broken lines (such as in a circle), but if the figures are difficult, sometimes breaks are obtained, incorrect ones, for example, one side of the rectangle fell off, etc.)

Then you need to divide the obtained lines in a convenient way for you into equal segments and extract points from them

`create table poly_buff_dump_pt as SELECT (ST_DumpPoints((geom))).geom geom FROM poly_buff_segm;`

Result, see Figure 4 below

[image]

Now run the Voronoi tool, in this place I used the tool suggested by the link MickyT :https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/172246/120129
, as a result of which you will have created tables with the name “voronoi” for the fact that “my first assistant” is separate from the chef thanks from the chef! :-).

The second way in this step is to run the ST_VoronoiPolygons function.

Result, see Figure 5 below

[image]

Now, cut off the extra parts by running the script:

`create table poly_voronoi_cut as SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM voronoi a INNER JOIN poly_extent b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);`

Result, see Figure 6 below.

[image]

Now run the script in order to align the geodata type in LineString:

`create table poly_voronoi_dump as SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom as geom  FROM poly_voronoi_cut;`
And now I will ask "my second mate" to take up my duties and mix the cake wel (Jeff - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/785/120129), leveling it in a single layer, and for that, thanks!

`CREATE TABLE poly_overlay_cut AS SELECT geom FROM ST_Dump((SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) AS geom FROM (SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom FROM (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(geom) AS geom FROM poly_voronoi_dump) AS lines) AS noded_lines));`
Now it’s time for me to get to work, for which I run the script:

`create table poly_voronoi_union as SELECT b.id, (ST_ConvexHull(ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom))) geom FROM poly_overlay_cut a INNER JOIN poly_buff_dump b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY b.id, a.geom, b.geom;`
and another script:

`create table poly_voronoi_union_area as SELECT ST_Union(ST_ConvexHull(ST_BuildArea(geom))) as geom FROM poly_voronoi_union GROUP BY id;`

see figure 7 below

[image]

As you can see in the picture, our cuts have small layers, which can be removed, as an option using ST_SnapToGrid (or in another way):

And finally, we will cut out our baked fruit from our pie, I even got a little tired standing by the oven, :-)

`create table polygon_voronoi_result as SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom as geom FROM poly_voronoi_union_area_snap as a JOIN poly b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);`

Result see figure 8

[image]

Everything from this day, now everyone will learn to bake delicious pies - fruit platter. Help yourself All, and choose the pieces you, likeenough for everyone.

(It’s a pity that I really can’t feed all people, not with electronic cakes, but with real cakes, perhaps hunger would end on Earth ...)

**Edit:** The cherry on the pie could look like this :-) :

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom geom FROM poly),
tblb AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblb a JOIN poly_extent b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom)),
tbld AS (SELECT id, ((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) geom FROM poly GROUP BY id, geom)
SELECT id, ST_Union(a.geom) as geom FROM tblc a JOIN tbld b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY id;
```

or

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom geom FROM polygons),
tblb AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT id, ((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) geom FROM polygons GROUP BY id, geom)
SELECT id, ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tblb a JOIN tblc b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY id;
```

Revise script 01.04.2020:

```
WITH tbla AS (
WITH atbl AS (SELECT id, (ST_ExteriorRing(((ST_Dump(geom)).geom))) geom FROM polygons),
intervals AS (SELECT generate_series (0, 501) as steps)
SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM intervals)) geom FROM atbl, intervals GROUP BY id, intervals.steps, geom),
tblb AS (SELECT ((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT id, ((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) geom FROM polygons GROUP BY id, geom)
SELECT id, ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tblb a JOIN tblc b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY id;
```

With you was good and fair Mr.Baker, thank you all and good luck, :-)...

Original solutions.

This script is called: ST_VoronoiDiagramsFromPolygons.

Edit:

SQL Function may look like this for now and only for one table and a small data set!!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_VoronoiDiagramsFromPolygons(
   geom GEOMETRY,
    n integer)
RETURNS TABLE (id bigint, geom GEOMETRY) AS  
$BODY$
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) geom FROM polygons),
tblb AS (SELECT id, ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) geom FROM tbla GROUP BY id, geom),
tblc AS (SELECT generate_series (0, n) as steps),
tbld AS (SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom FROM tblb, tblc GROUP BY id, stp, tblc.steps, geom),
tble AS (SELECT ST_MakeValid((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tbld)
    SELECT b.id, ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tble a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY id;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

RUN

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ST_VoronoiDiagramsFromPolygons(ST_Union(geom), 300)).* geom FROM polygons ORDER BY id;
```

Maybe someday the PostgreSQL and PostGIS developers will bring its behavior up to date  ...

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_VoronoiDiagramsFromPolygons(
   geom GEOMETRY,
   n integer)
RETURNS TABLE (geom GEOMETRY) AS  
$BODY$
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump($1)).geom),
tblb AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) geom FROM tbla GROUP BY geom),
tblc AS (SELECT generate_series (0, n) as steps),
tbld AS (SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblc)) geom FROM tblb, tblc GROUP BY stp, tblc.steps, geom),
tble AS (SELECT ST_MakeValid((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom) geom FROM tbld)
    SELECT ST_Union(a.geom) geom FROM tble a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY b.geom;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

RUN

`SELECT ST_VoronoiDiagramsFromPolygons(ST_Union(geom),100) geom FROM <polygon_name_table>`

(-: FOGS :-)...

Comment: Hi, good illustrations, and seems good result (!). Suggestion to a brief discussion, see @geogeek solution, the steps in QGis seems the main steps of PostGIS here... Why e need  `ST_Buffer` and `ST_ConvexHull`? There are an alternative algorithm?

Comment: 1) See, ST_Buffer and on polygons are created in order to reduce the separation lines between the original figures during the application of the Voronoi function, therefore, the larger the buffer size you can specify, the more smoothly the separation lines will be built as a Voronoi function ... 2) ST_ConvexHull from the multitude of figures on each polygon, the polygon we need ... 3) Today, this is my vision of solving your question, I don’t know what will happen to all of us and our decisions in the future ...

Comment: Another important value of the buffer lines is that they will help us select fragments from the result of the function of the Voronoi to create combined polygons for each shape ...

Comment: By the way, I welcome the improvement of the code and approach, so that they do not worsen the result ...

Comment: Hi Cyril, I agree that ST_Buffer is a good option to normalize the contour lines, perfect (!). About `ST_ConvexHull`, is only a curiosity, what kind of results we can obtain after Figure 6, `poly_voronoi_union` without ST_ConvexHull.

Comment: A possible (faster?) solution:  figure-6 regions can be coloured and converted into raster (with ST_AsRaster), them, back as polygon with [ST_DumpAsPolygons()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpAsPolygons.html).

Comment: It is necessary to conduct a study of your proposed solution, perhaps it will also give a good result, but I offered a vector solution to your question and do not claim that it is the best, I am sure that there are still good options for solving your interesting question in other ways, but I will note that this is not an easy solution, with respect...

Answer (score 9):

Postgis do not have a dedicated function for voronoi, but Qgis contains vornoi function which could make voronoi polygons from points, so using qgis i've followed the following steps to have these result:

-make points from polygons using `extract nodes` functions.

-make vornoi polygons using voroi functions in Qgis.

-make a spatial join in Qgis.

-dissolve results.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution (!), and thanks the illustration. Can you enhance it?  See the left rectangle below, it was 4 points at Voronoi, and the center of rectangle have no representantion, distorting its region (losting are to the triangle)... Perhaps enhance is possible doing a [regular sampling of each polygon](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/115341/7505)... and perhaps also some interior points.

Comment: I use densify tool in ArcGIS. This significantly improves proximity polygons. +1

Answer (score 4):

OK - Thought about this a little and found it was like something I have been looking at lately.

Take your starting polys:

[image]

Generate a new attribute with a number (100 in my case)
Use the Vector-> Research tools -> Random points inside polygons tool
this will generate (100) points inside each polygon:
[image]

Then Vector-> Geometry tools -> Voronoi to generate polys based upon that point layer.

[image]

Now, you can use the Vector -> Spatial Query tool:
Select the points that belong to one polygon (or one of the polygons)
Use the spatial query tool to generate a selection of your voronoi polygons which apply to that polygon.
Add an attribute to the voroni polygon which corresponds to the polygon of interest. (I just used 1,2,3,4)

Now you can Vector-> Geoprocessing Tools-> dissolve based upon your new attribute.

[image]

Comment: Thanks  @AAmes (!), the illustrations are good, and the method is a good alternative... But **the question is about "a SQL algorithm (or some specific for PostGIS)"** and now, the bounty  about the **use of the [function ST_VoronoiPolygons()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_VoronoiPolygons.html)**, that perhaps solve all problem in one click ;-)

Comment: @AAmes A quick search reveals that this method can indeed be used in PostGIS as well. [How to create random points in a polygon in postgis](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89954/how-to-create-random-points-in-a-polygon-in-postgis) explains the point creation from polygons and from there it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: My bounty was to you, as incentive (welcome here!), but **THIS ANSEWER IS WORNG** for the question and bounty requirements.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I saw your notes but unfortunately I have not had the opportunity to come back and address it.  I don't have any experience in PostGIS yet and it would have taken me more time than I had available to give any kind of good response.  I hope that our exploration of this space is helpful to people in the future, maybe If I get a crack at PostGIS soon I will come back and take another whack at it for practice!

Answer (score 3):

Random points are a good idea to generate a voronoi polygon from polygons, it works pretty well, but it's pretty bad for polygons close to each other:
[image]
[image]

ST_ApproximateMedialAxis is another good alternative if using PostGIS:
[Calculating Voronoi Diagrams for polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238936/calculating-voronoi-diagrams-for-polygons/279560#279560)

Comment: While close or overlapping polys wasn't in the original question, this is a good point.  If this was the case I would use a buffer to reduce the size of my initial polys before generating the random points.  That would help in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

I posted a mini python package to make it - [voronoi-diagram-for-polygons](https://github.com/longavailable/voronoi-diagram-for-polygons). It should be pointed out in advance that this package depends on v1.8.dev0 of [shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) which is still in development. In other words, the dependency of [voronoi-diagram-for-polygons](https://github.com/longavailable/voronoi-diagram-for-polygons) cannot be installed by `pip` automatically. You have to install the latest [Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) firstly by the following:

`pip install git+https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely`.

[image: input][image: output]

Comment: Hi Bruce, seems perfect! Can you [help to obtain a PostGIS wrapper function](https://github.com/longavailable/voronoi-diagram-for-polygons/issues/1)?